# jQuery position() consistently returns 0 on every second refresh

Tags: position, jquery

I have a wierd issue with jQuery which I've never seen before.

I have a bit of script to calculate the `position().top` value of an element which is always on the page. It's an `li` inside a `ul` inside a `div`.

The works every time I post a fresh request, normally returns `300`.
However if I then hit `ctrl-r` and redo the request, the same code for the same page returns `0` for `position().top`. Refreshing again sees it work.

This happens consistently, every `2nd` page refresh. However each fresh page request (with changed params or just resubmitting the form) seems to work fine. I haven't witnessed this strange failure cycle go out of sequence.

### caveats

Now on to the caveats (and a bit of code):
I'm using the [easing](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Easing) and [zebra_datepicker](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/) plugins, and have written my own vertical slider plugin which contains the code that consistently fails to get the right position of my element.

So I'm not expecting this to be a common occurrence, nor can I post the full source so instead I'm posting a snippet with the odd code for context more than anything else:

```
// inside each loop for slider parent elements
// $(this) references the slider container, i.e <div>
var slideTo = $(this).find('.slideTo').position().top; //300 or 0
```

This code is in the plugin itself, which is then called in a `$(window).load()` event.

The way this behaves makes me think it's some kind of race condition but I can't find anything in my code that does things in the wrong sequence or runs more than once, and believe me I've filled it to the gunnels with debug.

### tl;dr

So my question is this: are there any circumstances where `jQuery.position().top` will return `0`, given that the targeted element exists and has loaded by the time the call is made?

Are there any silly mistakes I could have made to make this happen; could it be due to invalid markup or maybe something to do with the fact that the element is an `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't *always* returning zero as I had thought.

What was happening is that when I modified the `scrollTop` of my parent element, then refreshed the page, Firefox *remembered* the `scrollTop` value on the refresh - so my calculation came back as zero then because with the remembered `scrollTop` value, the position of that element *was* zero.

So this behaviour was not buggy at all and `position()` was doing exactly what it should.

I got around this problem by setting the scrollTop of my elements to zero before running these calculations, which stopped Firefox's remembered value from breaking things for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is this in a Webkit browser? Is the element an image? Need some more information here, but in Webkit based browsers you will have problems accessing position values for images on $(window).ready() because it hasn't calculated their dimensions yet, you will have to wait until $(window).load()

I would assume the reason it works on the second load is because the images are cached, but then again I'm already assuming you're using Webkit and the element is an image...

edit: Sorry, just realised you said it was in $(window).load(), could you use setTimeOut to keep polling the value and see if it is populated some time after?

Comment: as I said in the question, the code is called on `$(window).load()` and the element is an `li`, and it does **not** work on second load. It works on first load and breaks every second **refresh**. Please re-read.

Comment: good suggestion with the timeOut thanks - I tried that but didn't get any different results. I did however notice something.... if I moved the `scrollTop` of the element, the `position().top` changed... I think my problem stems from the browser remembering the `scrollTop` of the element, and in fact `position()` is not acting buggy at all. More testing ahead...

Answer (score 0):

you can get [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) value with [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) so there will be only number value left;

try this:

```
var slideTo = parseInt($(this).find('.slideTo').css('top'));
```

Comment: good suggestion but the element has no css top value set; what I'm after is the element's position relative to its parent rather than the css values.

Comment: no, offset returns the position relative to the document, not the parent element which is what I need. also, I think I've figured out what the problem is, will be updating soon...